# Paginate API call in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, pagination, axios

I want to paginate the reults of an Api call.
I am making an Api Call by using Axios like this

```
apiCall() {
const API = `http://www.omdbapi.com/`;
axios.get(API, {
        params: {
            apikey: process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIECALL_API_KEY,
            type: 'movie',
            s: 'superhero',
            page: this.state.pageCount
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        const superheroes = res.data.Search
        const totalResults= parseInt(res.data.totalResults)
        this.setState({
            totalResults
        });
        this.setState({
            superheroes
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

When the component is mounted the function called, as such

```
  componentDidMount() 
    { 
     this.apiCall();
    }
```

In the render function I map over each search result (in the api call the s param  is the search option)
and for each result I display a button, that when clicked displays the related info of that movie.
The api by default displays 10 results per call but this particular search has 123 results in total. 
Now by updating the param page in the call which I've set to this.state.pageCount
it displays 10 different movies relating to that page, at the moment I hardcode the pageCount inside the state to make sure it works and the corresponding page number shows the right list of 10 movies.

Now I would like to paginate the results by updating the page number, so when you click on next or the number 3/4/5 then the component loads the correct corresponding results, I've tried a couple of option relating to react but they somehow don't update the page number.

If someone could point me in the right direction or knows a simple solution, I am all ears.

the following code is the whole component, to get an idea of what I am trying to do.

> What I have so far seems to be working, so what I am asking is for a
>   simpler more elegant way of doing pagination for this particular
>   situation.

```
export class MovieDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      superheroes: [],
      clicked: false,
      activeHero: {},
      pageCount: 11,
      totalResults: null,
      currentPage: 1
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }


  handleClick(hero) {
    const checkActive = this.state.activeHero.imdbID === hero.imdbID
    const activeHero = {...hero, active: !checkActive}
    this.setState({
      clicked: !this.state.clicked,
      activeHero
    })
  }    

  apiCall() {
    const API = `http://www.omdbapi.com/`;
    axios.get(API, {
            params: {
                apikey: process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIECALL_API_KEY,
                type: 'movie',
                s: 'superhero',
                page: this.state.pageCount
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            const superheroes = res.data.Search
            const totalResults = parseInt(res.data.totalResults)
            this.setState({
              totalResults
            });
            this.setState({
                superheroes
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.apiCall();
    }

    handlePageChange = (page, e) => {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: page
      });
      this.apiCall(this.setState({pageCount: page}))

    };


  render() {

    const {superheroes, currentPage } = this.state
    return (
        <div>
      {
        superheroes.map((hero, i) => 
            <div className="Results" key={i}>
            <button onClick={() => {this.handleClick(hero)}}> 
            <h1>{hero.Title}</h1>
            {
              this.state.clicked && this.state.activeHero.imdbID === hero.imdbID
                ? <ul>
                    {<div key={i}>
                    Movie Title: <h2> {hero.Title}</h2>
                      Year of Release: <h2>{hero.Year}</h2>
                      ID: <h2>{hero.imdbID}</h2>
                      <div><img className="Poster" alt="movieposter" src={hero.Poster}/></div>
                      </div>
              }
            </ul>
          : null
      }
      </button>
      </div>) 
   }
          <div className="Pagination"> 
          <Pagination
          total={this.state.totalResults}
          limit={10}
          pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
          currentPage={currentPage}
        >
          {({
            pages,
            currentPage,
            hasNextPage,
            hasPreviousPage,
            previousPage,
            nextPage,
            totalPages,
            getPageItemProps
          }) => (
            <div>
              <button
                {...getPageItemProps({
                  pageValue: 1,
                  onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                })}
              >
                first
              </button>

              {hasPreviousPage && (
                <button
                  {...getPageItemProps({
                    pageValue: previousPage,
                    onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                  })}
                >
                  {'<'}
                </button>
              )}

              {pages.map(page => {
                let activePage = null;
                if (currentPage === page) {
                  activePage = { backgroundColor: '#fdce09' };
                }
                return (
                  <button
                    {...getPageItemProps({
                      pageValue: page,
                      key: page,
                      style: activePage,
                      onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                    })}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </button>
                );
              })}

              {hasNextPage && (
                <button
                  {...getPageItemProps({
                    pageValue: nextPage,
                    onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                  })}
                >
                  {'>'}
                </button>
              )}

              <button
                {...getPageItemProps({
                  pageValue: totalPages,
                  onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                })}
              >
                last
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </Pagination>
          </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `axios.get` function you are sending `page: this.state.pageCount`, however in your `handlePageChange` function you are setting `state.currentPage` which doesn't seem right to me.

I'm also a bit confused about the `onPageChange` event on `<button />`. Is this button a custom component you are importing (in which case it should be capatalised so that it's clear) or is it a HTML button? If it's a HTML button then you need to use the `onClick` event which will pass the event as and argument to the `handlePageChange` function. I'm guessing it's custom though from the props you're passing it so just worth checking that it's sending the `page` value through correctly.